# Retirar localhost da chamada API - Angular

Tags: angular, api, http, get, localhost

Estou fazendo a chamada de API conforme código abaixo:

```
export class ModelosService {

  private readonly API: string = 'https//parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }



  listMarcas(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('Lista marca')
    return this.http.get(this.API).pipe(
      tap(marcas =>console.log('Res lista', marcas))
    );
    }
  };
```

Porém, está dando erro 404 pq está sendo adicionado  na url o localhost. Erro abaixo:

```
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "*http://localhost:4200*/https//parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas", ok:
```

Como acerto a configuração para que seja direcionada a página que preciso?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Sua url está incorreta, creio eu que corrigindo isso provavelmente já solucione a questão da url, falta `:` depois do `https`  -> `https:`

Comment: Alterei e funcionou!!! Muito obrigado